# Как массово получить координаты адресов используя геокодер от Яндекса?

Tags: яндекс-карты, геокодирование

Подскажите как мне массово получить координаты адресов используя геокодер от Яндекса?
У меня есть список из более 1000 адресов типа г Питер, ул Кирова, д.151/а, кв.10
Необходимо получить координаты типа 55.7578978987, 37.808769879.

P/S
Адрес и координаты выдуманные.

Comment: Используйте Exel файл через код макроса VAB.
Пример файла по ссылке: [ТУТ](https://excelstore.pro/examples-of-work/internet/get-the-address-and-coordinates-of-yandex-and-google.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Попробуй вот, у меня нет ключа до должно сработать либо минимальные правки нужны

import requests

API_KEY = "Ваш API-ключ"
BASE_URL = "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/"

def geocode(address):
    params = {
        'apikey': API_KEY,
        'geocode': address,
        'format': 'json',
    }
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL, params=params)
    data = response.json()

    try:
        coordinates = data['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['Point']['pos']
        return coordinates.split()
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        return None

addresses = [
    "г Питер, ул Кирова, д.151/а, кв.10",
]
coordinates_list = []

for address in addresses:
    coordinates = geocode(address)
    if coordinates:
        coordinates_list.append(coordinates)

for i, coordinates in enumerate(coordinates_list, start=1):
    print(f"Адрес {i}: {coordinates[0]}, {coordinates[1]}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Пример реализации множественного геокодирования Вы можете посмотреть на этой странице:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geocoding-docpage/

Обратите внимание, что результаты геокодирования должны отображаться на общедоступной карте и их нельзя сохранять к себе в БД (геокодирование должно происходить в момент запроса с клиента). Это будет нарушением условий использования и приведет к блокировке.

Comment: Прямо там же написано:Если на карте необходимо искать всегда одни и те же географические объекты, то нет смысла производить геокодирование на каждом клиенте отдельно. В этом случае целесообразно выполнить его один раз на стороне сервера и кэшировать полученный результат. А клиентам передавать уже данные, подготовленные для добавления на карту.